# MVC Get Method's Parameters Names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC 4 Project. I have HomeController, and 3 Actions on it.
And I want to list parameters when I send controller and actionname.
When I figure my problem,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetItem(string barcode, string param2)
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

And I want to write this method.

```
    public List<string> GetParametersName(string controller, string action)
    {
        //return - Method's Parameter(s) - **I DONT KNOW HOW CAN I WRITE THIS CODE**
    }
```

When I call the method

```
Class.GetParametersName("Home","GetItem");
```

It must me return, **"barcode, param2"**.

How can i write `GetParametersName`? Thanks.

Comment: I want to get parameter names, specify controller and action. Is it clear?

Comment: You could probably solve some of the issues by using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx), but I think you need to re-think this. An action method in a controller could have several different methods with the same name, but different parameters. What should be returned in that case?

Comment: No, "get parameter names, specify controller and action" isn't really clear. Can you explain some more what values should come from where?

Comment: Lars Kristensen, I research Reflection, yeah you right, I can write with it, but I cant write code, can you help me?

Comment: As I wrote before, you need to rethink this, because there might be some cases where it is not clear what should be returned. Maybe if you could explain why you need this, then we could try to help you with a solution.

Comment: I will have lots of Controller and Actions on it. When I run the application, only listing Controller names on the screen (with html anchor). And then, when I click a controller, will open Actions (actions list only have controller [not all actions, only clicked controller's actions]) And then, when I click an action, must be list parameters name.

Comment: Well, start by breaking it down to smaller tasks; Read about Reflection, and try to write a method that takes a class as a parameter, and returns all the Methods that return an ActionResult. Then iterate through those methods and inspect their parameters. I don't have time to attempt a solution right now, but at least you now know where to start :)

Comment: Really thank you for all your attension :)